# grep with regex pattern recursively

Tags: regex, grep

Regex pattern to search all recurences in string.

Ex- echo '%%MYSQL_PORT%%=%%3356%%' | grep \%%.*\%%

Actual output- %%MYSQL_PORT%%=%%3356%%

Expected output- %%MYSQL_PORT%% %%3356%%

Comment: `grep -oE '%%[^%]*%%'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
echo '%%MYSQL_PORT%%=%%3356%%' | grep -o '%%[^%]*%%'
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/3yDBHQ)

You need `-o` option to output the matches only and you should replace `.*` with `[^%]*` that will only match 0 or more chars other than `%` char.

Output:

```
%%MYSQL_PORT%%
%%3356%%
```